# Finding the average of certain numbers out of a text file

Tags: java, text-files, average

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 public class QuestionTwo
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
{
 System.out.println("Please enter a file name");
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

double average;
double numbertocheck;
int length;

String filename = keyboard.next();
Scanner reader = new Scanner (new File(filename));

length = reader.nextInt();

//Here is where I would put the statement that says "File is not found, enter the filename again"

System.out.println("The number to check: ");

numbertocheck = keyboard.nextDouble();

if (length > numbertocheck)
{
  //here is where I would put the average calculation

  System.out.println("The average of the numbers that are greater than" + numbertocheck + "is " /**+ average*/);

}

}
}
```

with the text file looking as such:

```
30
44
23
56
43
2
32
35
90
12
```

My output comes out to nothing; it simply asks the two questions and draws a blank (even before I made a bunch of things into comments). This code is attempting to answer the question:

"Write a program that asks the user to enter the name of a file that contains a set of integer values, and then asks the user to enter an integer number.

The program should display the average of the numbers
that are greater than the input number. Use Notepad or another text editor to create a simple file that can be used to test the program.

First, the user enters the file name as below:
Enter the file name: input.txt
and if, for example, the file ‘input.txt’ contains the following numbers:

```
30
44
23
56
43
2
32
35
90
12
```

and then, if the user enters an integer number, as:

```
The number to check: 40
```

the program should display the output as:

```
The average of the numbers that are greater than 40 is 58.25
```

Note that average of numbers 44, 56, 43 and 90 is 233/4 = 58.25. The average must be shown up to two decimal points.

If the input file is not found, the user must be prompted to enter the filename again with the following message

```
“File is not found, enter the filename again”.
```

Which will then prompt the question to be again until a valid file is found."

The problems arise for me when it comes to parsing the text file and finding the average of the numbers greater than the value asked for. That and looping the question asking the user to enter the file name and then repeating that question until a file is found. I have thought of using the Decimal format class, but do not know how to properly utilize it. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You only ever read one number from that file. The part where you "asks the user to enter an integer number" you actually read a double.

Comment: Professor DickButt.  I'd suggest you study your java FileIO documentation, try something, and then come back with specific questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first comment is you might want to take some lessons. This is pretty basic stuff.

But to answer your question, use a while loop, with an if/else statement inside, to get proper input.

For your next problem, you probably want to use .nextLine instead of .next, because some file names have spaces in them.

Third problem, use a for loop to check each integer one at a time, and compare it to the range needed. Then use if/if else statements/switch statements and an array to store the values, and after all values are checked, do the math on the content of the array.

Again, i highly recommended taking some basic java lessons.